# How do I put backslash in strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, formatting, markdown, ascii-art

So I'm making a cool terminal like 404 page for my fortnite stats site, I'm making so when you type a specific command it shows some ascii art, however whatever that's called is applying to the ascii art and removing a bunch of stuff like `/\` so its just `/`. Is there any way to stop this from happening? Thanks.

```
    function showFortnite(){
    $('.terminal').append("<div class='fortnite'>"+
                             "<p class='prompt'>                                                                                   ,---,  </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>                                                                                ,`--.' |  </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>    ,---,.                       ___                           ___              |   :  :  </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>  ,'  .' |                     ,--.'|_                ,--,   ,--.'|_            '   '  ;  </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>,---.'   |   ,---.    __  ,-.  |  | :,'       ,---, ,--.'|   |  | :,'           |   |  |  </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>|   |   .'  '   ,'\ ,' ,'/ /|  :  : ' :   ,-+-. /  ||  |,    :  : ' :           '   :  ;  </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>:   :  :   /   /   |'  | |' |.;__,'  /   ,--.'|'   |`--'_  .;__,'  /     ,---.  |   |  '  </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>:   |  |-,.   ; ,. :|  |   ,'|  |   |   |   |  ,' |,' ,'| |  |   |     /     \ '   :  |  </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>|   :  ;/|'   | |: :'  :  /  :__,'| :   |   | /  | |'  | | :__,'| :    /    /  |;   |  ;  </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>|   |   .''   | .; :|  | '     '  : |__ |   | |  | ||  | :   '  : |__ .    ' / |`---'. |  </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>'   :  '  |   :    |;  : |     |  | '.'||   | |  |/ '  : |__ |  | '.'|'   ;   /| `--..`;  </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>|   |  |   \   \  / |  , ;     ;  :    ;|   | |--'  |  | '.'|;  :    ;'   |  / |.--,_     </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>|   :  \    `----'   ---'      |  ,   / |   |/      ;  :    ;|  ,   / |   :    ||    |`.  </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>|   | ,'                        ---`-'  '---'       |  ,   /  ---`-'   \   \  / `-- -`, ; </p>" +
                             "<p class='prompt'>`----'                                               ---`-'             `----'    '---`   </p></div>");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `String.raw`, which will allow you to type single backslashes in a string without having to double-escape them. Normally, to use a literal backslash in a string, you need to escape it first, eg `'\\'` is a string literal with a single backslash in it. But, `String.raw` allows you to type *exactly what you want the string to be*.

The one issue is that `String.raw`'s delimiters are backticks, which can only be escaped inside a template literal with a backslash before every backtick, so to keep the art aligned properly, replace all backticks with some other character, such as `~`, while *writing* the art, and then replace all `~`s with backticks afterwards.

Also, use `<pre>`s with 0 margin to keep the alignment correct when displaying the text in the browser:

```js
const fortniteArt = String.raw`
                                                                                   ,---,
                                                                                ,~--.' |
    ,---,.                       ___                           ___              |   :  :
  ,'  .' |                     ,--.'|_                ,--,   ,--.'|_            '   '  ;
,---.'   |   ,---.    __  ,-.  |  | :,'       ,---, ,--.'|   |  | :,'           |   |  |
|   |   .'  '   ,'\ ,' ,'/ /|  :  : ' :   ,-+-. /  ||  |,    :  : ' :           '   :  ;
:   :  :   /   /   |'  | |' |.;__,'  /   ,--.'|'   |~--'_  .;__,'  /     ,---.  |   |  '
:   |  |-,.   ; ,. :|  |   ,'|  |   |   |   |  ,' |,' ,'| |  |   |     /     \ '   :  |
|   :  ;/|'   | |: :'  :  /  :__,'| :   |   | /  | |'  | | :__,'| :    /    /  |;   |  ;
|   |   .''   | .; :|  | '     '  : |__ |   | |  | ||  | :   '  : |__ .    ' / |~---'. |
'   :  '  |   :    |;  : |     |  | '.'||   | |  |/ '  : |__ |  | '.'|'   ;   /| ~--..~;
|   |  |   \   \  / |  , ;     ;  :    ;|   | |--'  |  | '.'|;  :    ;'   |  / |.--,_   
|   :  \    ~----'   ---'      |  ,   / |   |/      ;  :    ;|  ,   / |   :    ||    |~.
|   | ,'                        ---~-'  '---'       |  ,   /  ---~-'   \   \  / ~-- -~, ;
~----'                                               ---~-'             ~----'    '---~
`;
const htmlStr = "<div class='fortnite'>" + (
  fortniteArt
    .replace(/~/g, '`')
    .split('\n')
    .slice(1) // remove first empty line, which is there for spacing reasons
    .map(line => `<pre class='prompt'>${line}</pre>`)
    .join('')
) + '</div>';
$('.terminal').append(htmlStr);
```

```css
pre {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="terminal"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks a lot lol,
 Is there any way to get a scroll effect on this? I'm not extremely good at javascript. 
My old code had this:

  $('.new-output').velocity(
   'scroll'
  ), {duration: 100}

Comment: I don't know about `.velocity`, I was just answering the question posed, sorry

Comment: That's fine it doesn't really matter, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `p` with `pre`. Browser may leave whitespaces and special characters in `pre` as it is.

Comment: That just messed it up more, I figured out that if you do /\\ it shows /\
Thanks!

Comment: While your intentions were good, you should probably test your solution to make sure it works before posting it. `pre` tags indeed help with whitespace but won't fix backslash escaping in JavaScript.